# Fast reading the image header

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, tiff

Need to merge tons of various images into tiff file. The original images can have different encoding, resolution, color depth etc. If i parse them into bitmaps (img = Bitmap.FromStream()) before adding to the tiff then it will take too much time. The other way is to parse only headers, copy them to corresponding tiff's pages and then copy encoded data (like jpeg, png...) with no re-encoding.
What is a good way to fast parse all images headers? What libraries?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TIFF is not a container format that is designed to handle other image formats inside. You have to decode the image and then re-encode it using a TIFF supported image encoder.

The only exception is JPEG which can be included - using the JPEG-in-TIFF method introduced with TIFF 6.0: http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/support.html

If you only want to store images in a container it is better to save them in a ZIP file (with disabled compression) and add a meta data file for each image (e.g. XMP). That may suite you better.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, i'm using the library and played with JPEG, they can easily be added using WriteRawStrip method. I thought it would work for any file format :)